# Stop the System.Timers in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, .net-core, xamarin.forms

I'm using `System.Timers` and the Timer is doing it work perfectly e.g. On `Second 4, 8, 12, 16` take a Picture.

But, I want it to Navigate on `Second 17`, but It won't.

**Code**

```
public partial class CustomCameraPage : ContentPage
{
    private static Timer timer_click;
    int Seconds = 0;

    public CustomCameraPage()
    {
        timer_click = new Timer();
        timer_click.Interval = 1000;
        timer_click.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        timer_click.Enabled = true;
        timer_click.AutoReset = true;
        timer_click.Start();

        InitializeComponent();
    }
        
    public void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Seconds++;

        if (Seconds == 4 || Seconds == 8 || Seconds == 12 || Seconds == 16) MessagingCenter.Send<object>(this, "A");
        if (Seconds == 17) Navigation.PushModalAsync(new FormPage());
    }   
}
```

Comment: So nothing happens? Or is there an exception thrown what happens exactly?

Comment: Side Note: You're assumption that the timer's interval is exact is naive at best. your `Seconds` variable is not an accurate representation of the number of seconds passed since the timer have started, but rather an exact representation of the number of times the `OnTimedEvent` method was called.

Comment: And some nitpicking: `if (Seconds == 4 || Seconds == 8 || Seconds == 12 || Seconds == 16)` can be simplified to `if(Seconds < 17 && Seconds % 4 == 0)` but that's really just nitpicking...

Comment: @ZoharPeled thanks, any solution for the above problem :)

Comment: call `Stop()` on the timer, and execute your Navigation using MainThread from Xamarin Essentials

Comment: Are you allowed to push navigation from a different thread than the one owning the content page? I am unfamiliar with how Xamarin.Forms work in this regard.

Comment: Basically, you don't want to use `AutoReset = true;`  
Instead, add a `try...finally` block to your `Elapsed` event handler. In the `try` part you put all your code, and in the `finally` part start the timer again. This way, the timer will get started even if there was an exception thrown in the event handler.
Also, calling `timer.Start()` and setting it's `Enabled` property to `true` does exactly the same thing. Do one or the other, but not both; it's not going to have any effect of the code's performance, but it's going to be a shorter, more readable code.

Comment: Having said all that, I have no idea what's wrong in your particular case - I know nothing about xamarin, but I do have a lot of experience with timers in .Net.

Comment: @Jason can u please provider a simple sample? for me it's not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

execute the Navigation on the [MainThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/main-thread)

```
if (Seconds == 17) 
{
  timer_click.Stop();
  MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
  {
    Navigation.PushModalAsync(new FormPage());
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks, it worked :) but why it stuck for 1-2 seconds and then it navigates?